# how i parse following json array format. i want this filename value in bash or groovy?

Tags: shell-script, json, jq, jenkins

How do I parse the following json array format? I want the filename value `filewhichisdeploy` in bash or groovy

```
{
  "filewhichisdeploy":[
    {
      "filename": "value"
    },{
      "filename": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at **jq**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127091/parse-json-in-shell

Comment: Which `filename` value do you want for `filewhichisdeploy`: the first one, the second one, or both?

Comment: both value even there is 8-9 data i want all value

Comment: Related: [How to use jq to return information to the shell, taking whitespace into account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/712180/42620)

Answer (score 1):

You can pick all the `filename` values for `filewhichisdisplay` with `jq`

```
jq -r '.filewhichisdeploy[].filename' <file
```

Example

```
# Populate "file" with the sample json
cat >file <<'EOJ'
{
  "filewhichisdeploy":[
    {
      "filename": "value1"
    },{
      "filename": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
EOJ

# Pick out the key values
jq -r '.filewhichisdeploy[].filename' file
value1
value2
```

The `[]` is an unbounded array. You can choose particular numbered elements, for example the first is `[0]`.

Comment: should i put file path instead of file? i'm using it in jenkins pipeline

Comment: I have no experience with Jenkins so I can't advise you on that

Comment: def inputFile = new File("${jsonfilepath}")
 def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputFile)
 def foldername =InputJSON.filewhichisnotdeploy                   
   filename =foldername.filename  i used groovy for this so here [value, value] m getting but i'm stucking in  how to make it value value instead of  single string i want in two string

Comment: But those will be displayed newline-delimited, so you won't be able to get back to the list of filenames unless you can assume the file names don't contain newline character. May be better to use `|@sh` to generate some output that can be interpreted as shell code to store the list in an array for instance.

Comment: def inputFile = new File("${jsonfilepath}")
  def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputFile)
    def foldername =InputJSON.filewhichisnotdeploy
          filename =foldername.filename
           String[] arrOffilename = filename.split(","); 
           for(int i=0; i< arrOffilename.length; i++)
                     {
                      String[] arrOffile = arrOffilename[i].split(",")
                              for(int f = 0; f< arrOffile.length; f++){
                               excludedfiles = "--exclude=*${arrOffile[f]}*" }

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas i'm doing this can you check this once please

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas goal creep; the question asked for bash or groovy

Comment: And, how would `bash` or `groovy` the output of that command, when there's `"filename": "value\n1"` in the json file then?

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` and `jq` to build an array, `names`, of the names in the JSON document:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

unset -v names

code=$( jq -r '.filewhichisdeploy[] | @sh "names+=(\(.filename))"' file ) || exit

eval "$code"

if [[ ${#names[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo 'No names found' >&2
        exit 1
fi

printf 'Filename to deploy: "%s"\n' "${names[@]}"
```

This uses `jq` to build shell code for adding the filenames read from the JSON document to the array `names`.  The code, given the document in the question, would be

```bsh
names+=('value')
names+=('value')
```

This code is the evaluated with `eval`, the array's length is examined to see whether we actually got any values, and then we print the data read from the file (lacking anything more interesting to do with it).

Comment: `eval "names=($(jq -r '.filewhichisdeploy[].filename|@sh'))"` would be simpler. Those kind of approach do make me slightly uncomfortable though as we're having to trust `jq` not to output code that deviate from that array assignment whatever the input.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It would be good to understand when that might possibly happen. I'm trying to find that other comment that you wrote to me showing a case where it actually mattered a lot, but I can't find it. The case there was when the actual structure of the document turned out to be changed (I can't remember if you inserted an array instead of a scalar). I don't think it's `jq` you would have to trust, but the provider of the document (just like you would have to trust whoever wrote a shell script before you run it).

Comment: That was an array IIRC where `var='foo'` became `var='foo' 'reboot'` once the input changed from string to array. Here it's different as we're doing an array assignment, so that particular issue won't happen, but can something else happen? Not one I can think of. But any bug in `jq` could result in a command injection vulnerability, greatly amplifying the severity of the bug here. Which is why it's making me unconfortable. Maybe not a concern to the OP if the data source is  trusted.

Comment: Doing `code=$(jq...) || exit; eval "$code"` would also be preferable to avoid that evaluation if `jq` fails.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for that reminder, much appreciated! As soon as you have `eval` on input data, data turns into code, so you will have to start trusting the data provider as much as you trust the code provider. Hmm... Array assignments seems relatively safe, as you say, as would using `set --` be.

Comment: FYI, I also found that `|@sh` outputs the `"foo\u0000bar"` json string as `'foo\0bar'`, the same as for a `"foo\\0bar"` string (would still not introduce an ACE vulnerability), and that `jq` doesn't fail on non-properly UTF-8 encoded strings, replacing bytes not forming part of valid characters with U+FFFD (again, relatively safe, though I'd rather it failed, so we can detect the problem instead of treating it as if there were U+FFFD characters in the input)

Answer (score 1):

To store those of those values that are strings (not null, boolean, numbers, arrays, objects) and that don't contain the NUL (U+0000) characters (which cannot occur in a filename nor a bash variable, but we are otherwise using it to delimit the entries for `readarray -td ''`), in a bash array with the help of `jq`, you could do (assuming bash 4.4 or above):

```
readarray -td '' array < <(
  jq -j '.filewhichisdeploy?[].filename?|
           strings|
           select(index("\u0000")|not)|
           . + "\u0000"' file.json
)
wait "$!" || exit # abort if jq failed
```

That stores the filenames in the array as if they were text, and UTF-8 encoded. If you'd rather they be text in the locale encoding, you'd pipe it to `iconv -f UTF-8`:

```
readarray -td '' array < <(
  set -o pipefail
  jq -j '.filewhichisdeploy?[].filename?|
           strings|
           select(index("\u0000")|not)|
           . + "\u0000"' file.json |
    iconv -f UTF-8
)
wait "$!" || exit # abort if jq or iconv failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for a Jenkins Pipeline, there is a much easier way than anything suggested so far:

```
def json = readJSON(file: 'myJsonFile.json')
def filenames = json['filewhichisdeploy'].collect { it['filename'] }
```

`filenames` will be an array of the filenames.

Note this is for scripted Pipeline.  If you are using Declarative, you will need to put this in a `script` block.