# how to parse non-standard Json?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, json

I am using `curl` to retrieve data. the output is Json output but it's not standard. I tried using `jq` but i get null output. for example:

I want to extract all IDs from this output and store them in array:

```
  {"jsonrpc":"3","result":[{"hostid":"16729"},{"hostid":"16736"},{"hostid":"16731"},{"hostid":"16732"},{"hostid":"16733"},{"hostid":"16734"},{"hostid":"16735"},{"hostid":"16736"},{"hostid":"16738"},{"hostid":"16739"},{"hostid":"16746"},{"hostid":"16741"},{"hostid":"16742"},{"hostid":"16743"},{"hostid":"16744"},{"hostid":"16745"},{"hostid":"16746"},{"hostid":"16747"},{"hostid":"16748"},{"hostid":"16749"},{"hostid":"16756"},{"hostid":"16751"},{"hostid":"16752"},{"hostid":"16753"},{"hostid":"16754"},{"hostid":"16755"},{"hostid":"16756"},{"hostid":"16757"},{"hostid":"16758"},{"hostid":"16759"},{"hostid":"16766"},{"hostid":"16761"},{"hostid":"16762"},{"hostid":"16763"},{"hostid":"16764"},{"hostid":"16765"},{"hostid":"16766"},{"hostid":"16767"},{"hostid":"16768"},{"hostid":"16769"},{"hostid":"16776"},{"hostid":"16771"},{"hostid":"16772"},{"hostid":"16773"},{"hostid":"16774"},{"hostid":"16775"},{"hostid":"16776"},{"hostid":"16777"},{"hostid":"16778"},{"hostid":"16779"},{"hostid":"16786"},{"hostid":"16781"},{"hostid":"16782"},{"hostid":"16783"},{"hostid":"16784"},{"hostid":"16785"},{"hostid":"16786"},{"hostid":"16787"},{"hostid":"16788"},{"hostid":"16789"},{"hostid":"16796"},{"hostid":"16791"},{"hostid":"16792"},{"hostid":"16793"},{"hostid":"16794"},{"hostid":"16795"},{"hostid":"16796"},{"hostid":"16797"},{"hostid":"16798"},{"hostid":"16799"},{"hostid":"16866"},{"hostid":"16861"},{"hostid":"16862"},{"hostid":"16863"},{"hostid":"16864"},{"hostid":"16865"},{"hostid":"16866"},{"hostid":"16867"},{"hostid":"16868"},{"hostid":"16869"},{"hostid":"16816"},{"hostid":"16811"},{"hostid":"16812"},{"hostid":"16813"},{"hostid":"16814"},{"hostid":"16815"},{"hostid":"16816"},{"hostid":"16817"},{"hostid":"16818"},{"hostid":"16819"},{"hostid":"16826"},{"hostid":"16821"},{"hostid":"16825"},{"hostid":"16826"},{"hostid":"16827"},{"hostid":"16828"},{"hostid":"16829"},{"hostid":"16836"},{"hostid":"16831"},{"hostid":"11572"},{"hostid":"11573"},{"hostid":"11575"},{"hostid":"11576"},{"hostid":"11586"},{"hostid":"11629"},{"hostid":"11636"},{"hostid":"11632"},{"hostid":"11634"},{"hostid":"11736"},{"hostid":"11737"}],"id":1}
```

i expect this output:

```
  ( 16732 16733 ... 11737 )
```

even using python I didn't get the correct output. it kept returning jsonrpc. for example:

I want to extract ip value from this output

```
  {"jsonrpc":"3","result":[{"interfaceid":"400","hostid":"16796","main":"3","type":"3","useip":"3","ip":"192.168.23.43","dns":"","port":"100","details":[]}],"id":1}
```

it's just a long connected string. is there any way to achieve what i want with other commands like `sed` or `awk` ?

Comment: What is "not standard" - both JSON you posted is valid JSON - there's no such thing as not standard JSON by the way - data is either JSON, or it isn't - and what you posted, IS - perhaps if you show what you are doing, you can be shown why it is wrong

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing non-standard about your JSON documents.  Both are perfectly valid and well-formed JSON documents that you may query using any JSON-aware library or command-line tool.  For the examples here, I'm using `jq` on the command line.

Using `jq` to store all the `hostid` values in a `bash` array:

```bsh
readarray -t hostid_values < <( jq -r '.result[].hostid' file.json )
```

This would extract all `hostid` values from the `result` array in the JSON document and read them into elements of the `hostid_values` array in `bash`.  Any pre-existing values in the array would be removed.

Similarly for reading the `ip` values of your second JSON document into the array `ip_values` in `bash`:

```bsh
readarray -t ip_values < <( jq -r '.result[].ip' file.json )
```

Both these pieces of shell code assume that the values do not contain embedded newlines or nuls.

---

With newlines embedded in the values, you may want to try something like

```bsh
unset -v hostid_values
eval "$( jq -r '@sh "hostid_values+=( \(.result[].hostid | tonumber) )"' file.json )"
```

This uses `jq` to create assignment statements to the `hostid_values` array.  These assignment statements are then evaluated by the shell. That `tonumber` call makes sure that a malicious document can't inject code into our script by sending an array of commands instead of a string with a number in it (you'll get an error instead if that happens).

Similarly for the `ip` values in your second document:

```bsh
unset -v hostid_values
eval "$( jq -r '@sh "ip_values+=( \(.result[].ip | tostring) )"' file.json )"
```

Comment: Also assumes they don't contain NULs which bash can't store in its variables. See also [how i parse following json array format. i want this filename value in bash or groovy?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665254) for how to use NUL-delimited records along with bash 4.4+ `readarray -td ''`

Answer (score 0):

To create an array from your data with `sed`, you can try this command

```
array=($(sed 's/{"hostid":"\([0-9]*\)"},/\1 /g;s/{.*\[//;s/{.*:"\(.*\)"}/\1/;s/\].*//' input_file))
```

To extract the IP, you can try this `sed`

```
ip=$(sed 's/.*"ip":"\(.[^"]*\).*/\1/' iput_file)
```

**Output**

```
echo ${array[@]}
16729 16736 16731 16732 16733 16734 16735 16736 16738 16739 16746 16741 16742 16743 16744 16745 16746 16747 16748 16749 16756 16751 16752 16753 16754 16755 16756 16757 16758 16759 16766 16761 16762 16763 16764 16765 16766 16767 16768 16769 16776 16771 16772 16773 16774 16775 16776 16777 16778 16779 16786 16781 16782 16783 16784 16785 16786 16787 16788 16789 16796 16791 16792 16793 16794 16795 16796 16797 16798 16799 16866 16861 16862 16863 16864 16865 16866 16867 16868 16869 16816 16811 16812 16813 16814 16815 16816 16817 16818 16819 16826 16821 16825 16826 16827 16828 16829 16836 16831 11572 11573 11575 11576 11586 11629 11636 11632 11634 11736 11737
```

```
$ echo $ip
192.168.23.43
```