# How to use jq to return information to the shell, taking whitespace into account?

Tags: shell, quoting, jq

Given this file:

```
$ cat fruits.json
[
  { "name": "apple" },
  { "name": "banana\nfofanna" },
  { "name": "my kiwi" }
]
```

how can one use `jq` to retrieve a list of fruit names which the shell use as data, for example to populate an array?

Something equivalent to the assignment to the `fruits` array below:

```
$ fruits=( 
'apple'
'banana
fofanna'
'my kiwi'
)
$ for f in "${fruits[@]}" ;do echo "<$f>"; done
<apple>
<banana
fofanna>
<my kiwi>
```

None of the following work:

```
$ fruits=( $(jq -r ' .[].name       ' fruits.json))
$ fruits=( $(jq -r ' .[].name | @sh ' fruits.json))
$ fruits=( $(jq    ' .[].name | @sh ' fruits.json))
```

Comment: Similar: [how i parse following json array format. i want this filename value in bash or groovy?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/665068)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for that link - very informative and helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first two attempts at the end of the question do not work because they rely on the shell splitting the output of `jq` on whitespace.  Since newline is one type of whitespace, you lose the newlines (and tabs and the original spaces) in the data.

The attempts additionally fail to quote the string data, so you would get filename globbing happening if any string contained filename globbing characters.

The last attempt fails for similar reasons but additionally does not properly decode the data, leaving encoded newlines in place.

---

Using the built-in `@sh` operator in `jq` to quote the data and build an array assignment:

```bash
eval "$( jq -r '"fruits=(" + (map(.name)|@sh) + ")"' fruits.json )"
```

For the given JSON data, this would cause the following assignment to be evaluated by the current shell, creating the array `fruits`:

```bash
fruits=('apple' 'banana
fofanna' 'my kiwi')
```

After evaluating that statement,

```bash
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${fruits[@]}"
<apple>
<banana
fofanna>
<my kiwi>
```

---

As an alternative, the following would *append* each `name` element's value to the shell array:

```bash
$ jq -r '"fruits+=(" + (.[].name | @sh) + ")"' fruits.json
fruits+=('apple')
fruits+=('banana
fofanna')
fruits+=('my kiwi')
```

```bash
$ unset -v fruits
$ eval "$(jq -r '"fruits+=(" + (.[].name | @sh) + ")"' fruits.json)"
```

```bash
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${fruits[@]}"
<apple>
<banana
fofanna>
<my kiwi>
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention what shell; for ZSH one might use

```
% fru=( ${(fQg::)"$(jq '.[].name' ~/tmp/fru)"} )
% for f in $fru; printf '<%s>\n' $f
<apple>
<banana
fofanna>
<my kiwi>
% =echo -n "<${fru[2]}>" | od -bc
0000000   074 142 141 156 141 156 141 012 146 157 146 141 156 156 141 076
           <   b   a   n   a   n   a  \n   f   o   f   a   n   n   a   >
0000020
```

which performs the `jq` call, then `f` splits the result on newlines, and `Q` removes the quoting that the `jq` output leaves on the strings, and `g::` [acts like the builtin echo to perform interpolation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710182/how-to-make-zsh-interpret-n-in-parameter-expansion/710186) on such strings as `\n` in the input.

Comment: Interesting that this technique in `zsh` doesn't need to use `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers and comments from @Kusalananda, @roaima, and @StéphaneChazelas and in the [similar question mentioned in a comment above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665068/how-i-parse-following-json-array-format-i-want-this-filename-value-in-bash-or-g), I was able to come up with:

```
list=$( jq -r ' .[].name | @sh ' fruits.json ) || exit 1
eval "fruits=( $list )" || exit 1
printf "<%s>\n" "${fruits[@]}"
```